# Python script to run docker containers

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I want to write a python script that run docker containers and then show logs for that particular container, I have use some functions that are working and starting or stoping containers for me. Can somebody help me to show logs for the containers ?? 
I tried to use container.logs() function, but it is not working for me, i am also trying to study docker-py library !
I don't know much about python, any help will be highly appreciated !

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import docker
c = docker.Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',version='1.12',timeout=10)
ctr = c.create_container('ubuntu:16.04') 
c.start(ctr)
```

Comment: which version of docker are you using? You are using old python client it seems

Comment: Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
Python 2.7.12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a old docker client. Run below to fix that

```
pip uninstall docker-py
pip install docker
```

Once done you can use something like below

```
import docker

c = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',timeout=10)
ctr = c.containers.run('ubuntu:16.04',command="bash -c ' for((i=1;i<=10;i+=2)); do echo Welcome $i times; sleep 10; done'", detach=True) 
logs = ctr.logs(stream=True)

for line in logs:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Not running properly, will you please help a little !

======>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pydoc.py", line 3, in <module>
    c = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',timeout=10)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DockerClient'
<============

Comment: That means you still are on old client

Comment: Tarun, i have upgraded all the packages ... using this but still getting this error ! i have upgrade it using,
     `pip install --upgrade docker-py`
      `pip install --upgrade docker`

Comment: yes obviously i have first uninstalled it then i have again installed it !
But still it is not working fine !

Comment: Please test it in a fresh new virtual environment, the code has been tested on my end and then only shared. The code has nothing wrong. Please us https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

@Tarun , i come through it and it solved my problem , its easy !
by the way thanks for your help man !

```
import docker
import dockerpty

client = docker.Client()
container = client.create_container(
image='busybox:latest',
   stdin_open=True,
   tty=True,
   command='/bin/sh',
)
client.start(container)
dockerpty.PseudoTerminal(client, container).start()
```